# Tensoring of invetible sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme and let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_X$ - modules.
My question is

1. For any invetible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$, $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{L} \cong \mathcal{F}$?
2. If 1. is not true, then for any effect divisor $D$ and any closed subscheme $Y$,
   $\mathcal{O}_Y \otimes \mathcal{L}(D) \cong \mathcal{O}_Y$?

Comment: For 1. you should have checked $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}_X$ (the first nontrivial example!) first before asking this question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these claims are true. For example on $\mathbb{P}^n$, $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is a line bundle. Its sections are homogeneous linear polynomials, but when you tensor it by itself $n$ times you get $\mathcal{O}(n)$ whose sections are homogeneous degree $n$ polynomials so tensoring by it clearly is not an isomorphism.

For question two, if I understand your notation $\mathcal{L}(D)$ to mean the line bundle corresponding to $D$, then $\mathcal{O}_Y \otimes \mathcal{L}(D)$ is the line bundle on $Y$ corresponding to the the divisor $D|_Y$, which is not $\mathcal{O}_Y$ unless it's the trivial divisor.

Comment: Thanks you I solve my anxiety for your answer